# Convert Media tags to markup

Tags: 8, nodes

I imported the content of a website from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, but some nodes contain something like this.

```
[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"403","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"187","style":"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"480"}}]]
```

In Drupal 7 this is fixed by setting the filter "Convert Media tags to markup", which does not exist in Drupal 8.

How can I fix this in Drupal 8?

Comment: I have created a module which attempts to fix this by adding a text filter for this purpose: [Convert Media Tags to Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/convert_media_tags_to_markup).

Answer (score 1):

Your media token snippet is from the Drupal 7 [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) library and WYSIWYG integration.

I don't know if that integration exists yet in Drupal 8. It would apart of, listed as a project of the [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) project for drupal 8.

**EDIT**

You want to see the [Entity Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) module for Drupal 8 which supports WYSIWYG editors. I don't know if they offer a migration of old media content into this new module though.

These modules were found by these blog resources and DrupalCamp sessions which have a Youtube video showing these modules in action:

- https://drupalsquad.com/drupal-8-media-handling
- https://amsterdam2014.drupal.org/session/drupal-8-media  Media Ecosystem in Drupal8 drupalcamp youtube video can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd-jPrEcAn8

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- source D7
- destination D8 (i have not been able to make it work in D9 yet)
- source uses media_wysiwyg

in destination enable media_migration

in settings.php add:

$settings['media_migration_embed_token_transform_destination_filter_plugin'] =
'media_embed';

run the migration.

@huzooka has added a lot more detailed instruction is media_migration readme.

### Update

Looks like in D9 I have to :

a) actually call the plugin and

b) match the display modes

This worked:

```
 body:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: body
      process:
        value: value
        summary: summary
        format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: cc_wysiwyg
    -
      plugin: media_wysiwyg_filter
      view_mode_matching:
        default: full
        full: full
        teaser: teaser
        small: medium
```